# Compare each value in a variable that contains multiple whitespace-separated values

Tags: bash, text-processing

Normal case

```
wolf@linux:~$ x='10'
wolf@linux:~$ if [[ "$x" -eq 10 ]]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
True
wolf@linux:~$
```

My question, let say there are 2 values in `y` like this

```
wolf@linux:~$ y=' 10
>   10'
wolf@linux:~$
```

How do I verify if the number in `y` is equal to `10`?

```
wolf@linux:~$ if [[ "$y" -eq 10 ]]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
bash: [[: 10
  10: syntax error in expression (error token is "10")
False
wolf@linux:~$
```

Is this possible? If not, what is the right way to do it?

p/s - Sorry, not really sure what is the right title for this question. Will change it later (or please change it if you think it's necessary)

```
x='10'
y=' 10
   10'
   
if [[ "$x" -eq 10 ]]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
if [[ "$y" -eq 10 ]]; then echo True; else echo False; fi
```

Comment: You'd need to split out the two numbers, and test them separately. Also, to clarify what's going on here: the variable `y` contains a single *string value*, which just happens to contain two "10"s, some spaces, and a newline character near the middle.

Comment: your question is unclear, the second example should give *false* (because 10\n10 != 10) if you expect *true* then you must specify additional requirements. a common way to process each value for it's own is using word splitting in loop: *for var in $y; do [ "$var" = 10 ] && echo "y=$var true" || echo "y=$var false"; done* (to avoid syntax error use `=` instead `-eq`) or give just one result (*true/false*) for all tests (*and/or*)

Comment: @alecxs, no, it should give an error since `-eq` is an arithmetic test, and ` 10\n  10` isn't a number. (Or a valid arithmetic expression)

Comment: _"there are 2 values in y"_ and _"**the** number in y"_ are in contradiction, there can't be both one value and two values in y at the same time. The question that should be asked is what should be done with those two numbers. Check if one of them is 10? Check if both/all of them are equal? Check them all separately and give multiple results? (Sum them?) Or perhaps it really should be an error that there are two values instead of one, and the output should make that clear, instead of showing "False"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 values are actually different. `y` is not equal to `10`.

```
x='10'
y=' 10
   10'
```

That's the reason you're getting False in your output. Echo both variables to see their actual value.

```
$ echo $y
10 10
$ echo "$y"
 10
   10
$
```

If you want to make it True, try the code shared by alecxs.

```
for var in $y; do [ "$var" = 10 ] && echo "y=$var true" || echo "y=$var false"; done
```

Sample output

```
$ for var in $y; do [ "$var" = 10 ] && echo "y=$var true" || echo "y=$var false"; done
y=10 true
y=10 true
$
```

or, you can also do this way, save it to a file, or run it directly from the terminal

```
for var in $y; do
 if [[ "$var" = 10 ]]; then
  echo "y=$var True"
 else
  echo "y=$var False"
 fi
done
```

Sample output

```
$ for var in $y; do
>  if [[ "$var" = 10 ]]; then
>   echo "y=$var True"
>  else
>   echo "y=$var False"
>  fi
> done
y=10 True
y=10 True
$
```

Comment: The reason they're getting a "False" in the output is that the string ` 10\n   10` isn't a valid arithmetic expression, and the exit status for an error is falsy when used in an `if`. You could try with `y="5+5"; if [[ "$y" -eq 10 ]]; then echo true; fi`. Of course that wouldn't work with `=`, since that's a string comparison, not an arithmetic comparison.